# I can't display html code - Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

(I'm a beginner in the web scraping) I want to **scrape** this link:
https://www.seloger.com/list.htm?tri=initial&idtypebien=1,2&pxMax=3000000&div=2238&idtt=2,5&naturebien=1,2,4&LISTING-LISTpg=2

when I tried to display repo_list I get that [] and not html code !!!`

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('https://www.seloger.com/list.htm?tri=initial&idtypebien=1,2&pxMax=3000000&div=2238&idtt=2,5&naturebien=1,2,4&LISTING-LISTpg=2')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
repo = soup.find(class_="c-wrap")
print(repo)
repo_list = repo.find_all(class_='c-pa-list c-pa-sl c-pa-gold cartouche ')
print(repo_list)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can regex out, do a little string cleaning and then pass to json to then print out each product as dictionary containing the info for each listing

```
import re
import requests
import json

r = requests.get('https://www.seloger.com/list.htm?tri=initial&idtypebien=1,2&pxMax=3000000&div=2238&idtt=2,5&naturebien=1,2,4&LISTING-LISTpg=2', headers = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0'})
p = re.compile('var ava_data =(.*);\r\n\s+ava_data\.logged = logged;', re.DOTALL)
x = p.findall(r.text)[0].strip().replace('\r\n    ','').replace('\xa0',' ').replace('\\','\\\\')
x = re.sub(r'\s{2,}|\\r\\n', '', x)
data = json.loads(x)

for product in data['products']:
    print(product)
```

Example return (from page 3):

```
{'idannonce': '142830891', 'idagence': '263765', 'idtiers': '284402', 'typedebien': 'Appartement', 'typedetransaction': ['vente'], 'idtypepublicationsourcecouplage': 'SL', 'position': '0', 'codepostal': '77450', 'ville': 'Esbly', 'departement': 'Seine-et-Marne', 'codeinsee': '770171', 'produitsvisibilite': 'AD:AC:BB:AW', 'affichagetype': [{'name': 'liste', 'value': True}], 'cp': '77450', 'etage': '0', 'idtypechauffage': '0', 'idtypecommerce': '0', 'idtypecuisine': 'séparée équipée', 'naturebien': '1', 'si_balcon': '0', 'nb_chambres': '1', 'nb_pieces': '2', 'si_sdbain': '0', 'si_sdEau': '0', 'nb_photos': '14', 'prix': '139900', 'surface': '44'}
```

Price for example is:

```
product['prix']
```

Answer (score 2):

When you call `find_all` it's returning a list of tags to a subset of the html, if there are no matching tags then it returns an empty list. So the tag you're searching for isn't found in the page! This could be for a number of reasons. You may have a typo in the class you're searching for or maybe the value you're searching for is not a class but an id or some other attribute.

It's also the case that some pages (usually larger web-apps like facebook, instagram, twitter, etc) will dynamically create classes, ids, etc and do little tricks to keep their data from being scraped. If you want to see what a website will *allow* you to scrape, you can check what's called the `robots.txt`.

For instance, if you wanted to scrape reddit, you could go to https://reddit.com/robots.txt and see a list of the uri's you can hit from their domain! Sites will also include a `sitemap` which is an xml (similar to html) document full of links to available pages!

Answer (score 1):

Great Tutorial:

## https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ind-mugxMxk

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from babel.numbers import format_currency

session = requests.session()
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0',
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5', # these parameters can be changed as needed
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'skip-caching': 'true',
    'DNT': '1',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'TE': 'Trailers'}
url = 'https://www.seloger.com/list.htm?tri=initial&idtypebien=1,2&pxMax=3000000&div=2238&idtt=2,5&naturebien=1,2,4&LISTING-LISTpg=2'
response = session.get(url, headers=headers)
page = response.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")
for i, div in enumerate(soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'c-pa-price'}), 1):
    price = div.text
    # this regular expression substitution replaces all non alphanumeric characters but leaves in specialized language characters
    price = re.sub('[^0-9A-Za-z\u00c0-\u00d6\u00d8-\u00f6\u00f8-\u02af\u1d00-\u1d25\u1d62-\u1d65\u1d6b-\u1d77\u1d79-\u1d9a\u1e00-\u1eff\u2090-\u2094\u2184-\u2184\u2488-\u2490\u271d-\u271d\u2c60-\u2c7c\u2c7e-\u2c7f\ua722-\ua76f\ua771-\ua787\ua78b-\ua78c\ua7fb-\ua7ff\ufb00-\ufb06]+','', price)
    # remove extra word Bouquet - optional
    extra_word = re.compile('Bouquet')
    if extra_word.search(price):
        price = price.split('Bouquet')[1]
    price = format_currency(int(price), 'EUR', locale='fr_FR')
    print('Inscription ' + str(i) + ':', price)
```